# Plotting a function involving Nsolve in its definition

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, recursion

Here is the function in `H, rhoc` I am trying to plot with `ContourPlot`

```
    Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity},
    beta = 10000; Mpl = 1; phiinf=0.00255142;
    rhoinf = 0.0000001; n = 2; M = 1; minf=1.16006*10^6;

    phicv[rhoc_] := 
    NSolve[-n*M^(4 + n)/phi^(n + 1) + beta*rhoc*Exp[beta*phi/Mpl]/Mpl == 
    0, phi, Reals];
    phic[phicv_] := phicv;

    mc[phic_,rhoc_] := (n*(n + 1)*M^(4 + n)/phic^(n + 2) + 
    beta^2*rhoc*Exp[beta*phic/Mpl]/Mpl^2)^0.5;

     ContourPlot[ mc[phic[phicv[rhoc]],rhoc]^2*((Mpl*phiinf/(beta*rhoc) - H^2/2 - H/minf) - 
  phic[phicv[rhoc]]*Mpl/(beta*rhoc)) == 1, {rhoc, 1, 5}, {H, 1, 5}];
     ]
```

Mathematica spits out error >NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve. This only occurred after I make `NSolve` part of a function definition. In other words, the equation can be solved when all parameters are definite.

I have tried simpler functions and the function definition worked out fine with `NSolve`. How can I fix my problem here?

Comment: you are missing the `:` in your function definitions. They should be of the form `f[x_] := (...)`

Comment: @gIS I have corrected them now. But it doesn't seem to solve the problem :/ @Kuba Are you referring to the expression inside `ContourPlot`?

Comment: @Kuba Oh I see. Thanks. Still not working though... :/

Comment: What about using `FindRoot` instead?